# Create clickable PDF mockup

Tags: pdf, user-interface, mockups, interaction-design

I am designing a new user interface and have the created images for each new screen. Now I want to combine these images in a clickable PDF so that by clicking on buttons within the images you can navigate from one screen to another.

What is the easiest way to create a clickable PDF? (Free Tools?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pencil Project is a free prototyping tool that allows you to create clickable PDFs.
http://pencil.evolus.vn/Default.html
Good luck! Some people use Microsoft Excel for prototyping, but I'm not recommending doing that.